# FileStream.writeObject produces unwanted characters

Tags: actionscript-3, file, air, character-encoding

I try to write an xml object via AIR with FileStream.writeObject

I'm doing like this:

```
var _file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("test.xml");
var _xml:XML = new XML("<data><name>Testname</name><email>test@test.de</email><time>1331290186848</time></data>");

stream = new FileStream()
stream.open(_file, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeObject(xml);
stream.close();
```

unfortunately, this is the result

```
Å<data>
   <name>Testname</name>
   <email>test@test.de</email>
   <time>1331290186848</time>
</data>
```

since i don't have any influence on the process, how can i prevent AIR to write those strange chars?

thank you!

Comment: Not sure, but I think you should just write your XML as a String using writeUTF() or writeUTFBytes()

Comment: Actually I _am_ sure ;) Otherwise you would write it as an XML Object, hence the strange chars.

Comment: writeUTF produces the same problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write your XML to the file as a String. Right now you're writing it as an XML object, which looks a lot like a String, but has some additional information. I think that strange character at the start represents the length of the String.

Use [writeUTFBytes()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#writeUTFBytes%28%29) instead of writeObject().

So replace

```
stream.writeObject(xml);
```

with

```
stream.writeUTFBytes(xml.toXMLString());
```

writeUTF() won't do the trick either: if you read [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#writeUTF%28%29), you'll see that it writes the length of the String as the first character too.